# What is the charging current specification of a BMS?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm planning on using this BMS: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3S-11-1V-25A-Li-ion-Lithium-18650-BMS-PCM-battery-protection-board-bms-pcm-with/32816991614.html

And 3 Samsung 18650 cells in series: http://dalincom.ru/datasheet/SAMSUNG%20INR18650-25R.pdf

In the datasheet of the cells it says that "Charging current shall be less than maximum charge current specified in the product
specification". I suppose that maximum charge current is 4A since that is the Rapid charge current as mentioned in the datasheet.

The BMS doesn't give any specification for its typical charging current. So how do I know if it exceeds the 4A?

Also the input voltage range of the BMS is not given. Of course it is at least 12.6V but what is the maximum? Can I hook up a laptop charger?

Comment: That is a cell balancer, not a battery charger.

Comment: That does make sense. If I look at this board: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/30A-3S-Polymer-Lithium-Battery-Charger-Protection-Board-3-Serial-12V-3pcs-18650-3-7-Li/32780248457.html, it only mentions that the charging current is less than 10A. Should I be worried or does it know not exceed the 4A?